# Bad pixel removal using dask array

Tags: python, dask

I have a very large 4 dimensional dataset, where the two last dimensions are images taken on an image detector. Some of the pixels on this detector does not work, and these dead pixels gives a value of 0. I'd like to set the value of these pixels to the median of their neighbors in post processing. The datasets range from 8 GB to possibly TB size, so I'd like to use dask array, since I can chain the dead pixel removal together with other processing steps.

Finding the dead pixels is easy, but I'm not certain how to best get the median of the neighbors.

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

data = np.random.randint(10, 50, size=(10, 10, 20, 20))
data[:, :, 2, 7] = 0
data[:, :, 9, 3] = 0
dask_array = da.from_array(data, chunks=(5, 5, 5, 5))
dask_array_mean = dask_array.mean(axis=(0, 1))
dead_pixels = dask_array_mean == 0

# Some kind of processing

dask_array_without_dead_pixels = dask_array + dead_pixel_values_array
```

So my question is: how do I get `dead_pixel_values_array`? Or some other clever way of removing the dead pixels?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of regional median for dask arrays: https://dask-ndfilters.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dask_ndfilters.html#dask_ndfilters.median_filter

If you wanted something more general yourself, or don't wish to install `dask_ndfilters`, you should read up on [`map_overlap`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-ghost.html) which allows you to access data around each chunk that comes from adjacent chunks, and so allows for the kind of computation you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by firstly rechunking the image dimensions (the two last) to one chunk, and then using `map_blocks`. `map_overlay` worked for small datasets, but for the larger ones the memory usage was way more than the available memory.

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def remove_dead_pixels(data, dead_pixels):
    dif0 = np.roll(data, shift=1, axis=-2) * dead_pixels
    dif1 = np.roll(data, shift=-1, axis=-2) * dead_pixels
    dif2 = np.roll(data, shift=1, axis=-1) * dead_pixels
    dif3 = np.roll(data, shift=-1, axis=-1) * dead_pixels
    output_data = np.median(np.stack([dif0, dif1, dif2, dif3], axis=-1),
                            axis=-1, overwrite_input=True, keepdims=False)
    return output_data

# Making artificial data
data = np.random.randint(10, 50, size=(10, 10, 20, 20))
data[:, :, 2, 7] = 0
data[:, :, 9, 3] = 0
dask_array = da.from_array(data, chunks=(5, 5, 5, 5))
dask_array = dask_array.rechunk((5, 5, 20, 20))

# Finding dead pixels
dask_array_mean = dask_array.mean(axis=(0, 1))
dead_pixels = dask_array_mean == 0

# Getting replacement values
dead_pixel_values_array = da.map_blocks(
        remove_dead_pixels, dask_array, dead_pixels, dtype=dask_array.dtype,
        chunks=dask_array.chunks)
dask_array_without_dead_pixels = dask_array + dead_pixel_values_array

# Plotting result
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
axarr[0].imshow(dask_array.sum(axis=(0, 1)).compute())
axarr[1].imshow(dask_array_without_dead_pixels.sum(axis=(0, 1)).compute())
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("image.jpg")
```

[image: Left image: data with two dead pixels. Right image: data with the dead pixels removed]